# How to retrieve BAi2 bank statement files after processing from oracle fusion

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher, oracle-fusion-apps, oracle-rest-data-services

I am looking for a way to download BAI2 files that are imported into Oracle Fusion as a way to create a back-up. Our current process is that Oracle Fusion imports the BAI2 file from the Bank SFTP site. Once it is downloaded the Bank removes it from the SFTP site and I can't run a separate internal process to save a copy of that BAI2.
I thought that since it is in Oracle after the import that there might be a way for me to download it via some type of report.